# how to create a dataframe column that contains a list of the indices of the last 3 times True occured in an already existing column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am not quite sure if I managed to articulate the question properly, but I am wondering how could I create a column that keeps track of the last 3 times there's a True in another column, my dataframe looks somewhat like this with date as the index, suppose

```
2021-03-22            True       [None, None, None]  
2021-03-23            True       [None, None, None]   
2021-03-24            True       [2021-03-22, 2021-03-23, 2021-03-24]   
2021-03-25            False      [None, None, None]   
2021-03-26            True       [2021-03-23, 2021-03-24, 2021-03-26]
```

The last column above is the kind of format I would like for the new column. The first two rows are NaN's because, I need at least 3 rows of data to figure the pattern in the first place, the 4th row is NaN's because, I only need the pattern when the second column contains a True.

I actually need this to do someother bigger calculations with other columns, but first I need a list of indices for every row where the second column's value is True, Appreciate any help with the same, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with loading the data:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(
'''
2021-03-22            True 
2021-03-23            True 
2021-03-24            True 
2021-03-25            False
2021-03-26            True
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data ,sep = '\s+', header=None)
df
```

so it looks like this:

```
    0           1
0   2021-03-22  True
1   2021-03-23  True
2   2021-03-24  True
3   2021-03-25  False
4   2021-03-26  True
```

Now apply the logic:

```
df.loc[df[1] == True, 2] = [w.to_list() for w in df.loc[df[1] == True, 0].rolling(3)]
df.loc[df[1] == False, 2] = ''
```

we get

```
    0           1       2
0   2021-03-22  True    [2021-03-22]
1   2021-03-23  True    [2021-03-22, 2021-03-23]
2   2021-03-24  True    [2021-03-22, 2021-03-23, 2021-03-24]
3   2021-03-25  False   
4   2021-03-26  True    [2021-03-23, 2021-03-24, 2021-03-26]
```

now replace 'short' lists with None's as requested

```
df[2]  = df.apply(lambda row: row[2] if len(row[2])==3 else [None, None, None], axis=1)
df
```

and we get

```
    0           1       2
0   2021-03-22  True    [None, None, None]
1   2021-03-23  True    [None, None, None]
2   2021-03-24  True    [2021-03-22, 2021-03-23, 2021-03-24]
3   2021-03-25  False   [None, None, None]
4   2021-03-26  True    [2021-03-23, 2021-03-24, 2021-03-26]
```

Comment: perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you need Series.shift() function. You can use it to create a column with Date list like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({                         # dummy data
    0:['2021-03-22', '2021-03-23', '2021-03-24', '2021-03-25', '2021-03-26','2021-03-27','2021-03-28','2021-03-29',],
    1:[True, True, True, False, True, False, False, True],
    },)

tdf = df[df[1] == True]                     # copy rows with True only

tdf[2] = list(                              # column: i-2 to i date list
            map(list, zip(                  # converts tuple to list
                tdf[0].shift(2),            # i-2 date
                tdf[0].shift(1),            # and so on
                tdf[0].shift(0),            # ...
                )
            )
        )

tdf.iat[0, 2] = [None, None, None]          # 1st cell set to None list
tdf.iat[1, 2] = [None, None, None]          # 2nd cell set to None list
```

Once you have the column with Date list, you can add it to the original dataframe.

```
df = df.set_index(0)                        # prepare for update()
tdf = tdf.set_index(0)                      # date index matches with df's
df[2] = [[                                  # set all with None list
    None, None, None
    ] for _ in range(df.shape[0])]
df[2].update(tdf[2])                        # update col based on index
```

tdf has "True" rows only, so Series.update() replaces those rows only.

```
print(df)
                1                                     2
0                                                      
2021-03-22   True                    [None, None, None]
2021-03-23   True                    [None, None, None]
2021-03-24   True  [2021-03-22, 2021-03-23, 2021-03-24]
2021-03-25  False                    [None, None, None]
2021-03-26   True  [2021-03-23, 2021-03-24, 2021-03-26]
2021-03-27  False                    [None, None, None]
2021-03-28  False                    [None, None, None]
2021-03-29   True  [2021-03-24, 2021-03-26, 2021-03-29]
```